# After SaveChangesAsync() visual studio crashes

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have a project which was built on VS2015. The project is connected to TFS. I took the project and deployed it on some other environment which has VS2013. Anyway, when i'm running the project, the VS crashes when it gets to the SaveChangesAsync()... method.
If I use the old n good SaveChanges() it doesn't crash.

Anyone has an idea why does it happen?
[image]

Comment: SaveChangesAsync is only available in Entity Framework 6.0 - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechangesasync(v=vs.113).aspx - can VS2013 build EF6.0 projects?

Comment: If not, how is that I can do 'Build'?